# Trying to deploy website on render.com not working

Tags: mongodb, express, ejs, web-hosting, render.com

I am trying to deploy an app I made with express, ejs and mongodb. render  says my service is live but I keep getting "this page isnt working HTTP ERROR 502" when I load the page.

````
//is thus a possible reason => Aug 3 05:37:25 PM  ==> No open HTTP ports detected.
//Aug 3 05:37:26 PM  ==> https://render.com/docs/web-services#host-and-port-configuration
Aug 3 05:37:46 PM  ==> Using Node version 14.17.0 (default)
Aug 3 05:37:46 PM  ==> Docs on specifying a Node version: https://render.com/docs/node-version
Aug 3 05:37:46 PM  ==> Starting service with 'npm start'
Aug 3 05:37:47 PM  
Aug 3 05:37:47 PM  > tinisha-nail-tech@1.0.0 start /opt/render/project/src
Aug 3 05:37:47 PM  > node server.js
Aug 3 05:37:47 PM  
Aug 3 05:37:51 PM  Connected to MongoDB
Aug 3 05:37:51 PM  Server is running on http://localhost:3000
Aug 3 05:37:56 PM  Your service is live 
Aug 3 07:07:09 PM  ==> Using Node version 14.17.0 (default)
Aug 3 07:07:09 PM  ==> Docs on specifying a Node version: https://render.com/docs/node-version
Aug 3 07:07:09 PM  ==> Starting service with 'npm start'
Aug 3 07:07:10 PM  
Aug 3 07:07:10 PM  > tinisha-nail-tech@1.0.0 start /opt/render/project/src
Aug 3 07:07:10 PM  > node server.js
Aug 3 07:07:10 PM  
Aug 3 07:07:15 PM  Connected to MongoDB
Aug 3 07:07:15 PM  Server is running on http://localhost:3000```

any ideas why this might be happening
````

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your start command to `npm run start` in the settings page of the render.com dashboard.

It is hard to tell with the information given, but the issue could be that your start command. I always need to use `npm run start` but you are using `npm start`. Some tutorials seem to make the mistake (and then change it later). If you followed one, they may have led you wrong.

`npm run <script-name>` calls a script from your `package.json` file. If you leave out the "run" keyword, npm doesn't know what to do. Also, my start command looks like this, and yours should be similar:

```json
"scripts": {
  "start": "node build/app.js",
  "another-script": "you get the idea"
},
```